# Apache vhosts not rewriting url to site root

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have my domain `example123.com` pointing to my apache server.

I have a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example123.com.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        ServerName example123.com
        ServerAlias www.example123.com
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example123.com
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/example123.com>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I've activated the site with `a2ensite example123.com.conf`

The site was working great until this morning. I did a couple things.
I enabled apache mods expires and headers
`a2enmod expires` and `a2enmod headers`

and I allowed a caching plugin(wordpress) to write to my .htaccess file in my sites root folder. I have since deleted that .htaccess file.

So the problem I'm having is when I got to `example123.com` it goes to `/var/www` and shows the directory tree rather than showing the site in `/var/www/example123.com`

`apache2ctl -S` shows

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example123.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example123.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example123.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example123.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.example123.com
         port 80 namevhost anothersite123.cc (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/anothersite123.cc.conf:1)
                 alias www.anothersite123.cc
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing in /var/www/example123.com ? The best way is to put AllowOverride to None for that directory, so even if there's a .htaccess there, it won't be taken into account.

Comment: It's the weirdest thing. Yeah, there is a site inside example123.com. When I go to the url example123.com it brings me to /var/www. I can then choose the folder example123.com which then makes my url example123.com/example123.com. I get a 'oops nothing here' page from my wordpress install

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by setting a ServerName in 000-default.conf

I set the servername to the ip address of my server.

Not really sure why this worked.